# 1 click backup for my websites

Tags: backups

I have a windows reseller account that I only really use for personal use. The host company doesn't currently offer a 1 click backup.  I am looking for something to automate some kind of backup that does the following:

- Backups all files
- Backups all databases

I know other companies offering such a tool but I am not looking.  I have thought about writing a tool that does this but thought there might be something out there that does this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use something like [backblaze](http://www.backblaze.com/index-k.html) or [mozy](http://www.mozy.com)? I've not tried using these on a server, but you could then setup the sql server to backup to a particular location then backup that directory using one of the above. You could definitely use the above tools to backup the files.

For the sql server, you could use something like Red Gate's [SQL Backup](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-backup/), but you'd probably want to back the database up off-site.

I should probably note, that none of the above can really be called "one click", but it's certainly something to consider.

Also, I'm assuming that you have remote access to the server and that you're not using any sort of shared hosting.

**Edit**

Just noticed that you've got a reseller account. I don't think that there's really going to be much around that you can use. I would suggest moving to an account where you have remote access (i.e. admin access) or move to some kind of Linux hosting where you have cron available.

Comment: Hmmmm you have given me an idea.  Cheers Piers :)